# PostgreSQL: Why not remove index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I hope to remove index in table, but it occurs not remove index.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON schema_name.table_name(column1, column2);
```

And, remove index

```
DROP INDEX idx_name;
```

but, it fail.

error message is

> ```
> ERROR: index "idx_name" does not exist
> ```

How I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify schema if it isn't in your search path.

```
DROP INDEX schema_name.idx_name;
```

To clarify:

> The name of the index to be created. No schema name can be included here; **the index is always created in
>   the same schema as its parent table**